# The Reason Phrase Must not Contain New Line Characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api

I was getting below error while trying to execute SQL Query through an application.

> Error: The Reason Phrase must not contain new line characters.

When I turned off integrated security option, the error was gone.

Please advise why this error was coming and what was the reason behind this?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a [tag:sql-server] error message.

Answer (score 2):

It is not error of sql-server. The problem in property [`HttpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.reasonphrase(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public string ReasonPhrase
{
    get { return reasonPhrase; }
    set
    {
        if ((value != null) && ContainsNewLineCharacter(value))
        {
            throw new FormatException("The reason phrase must not contain new-line characters.");
        }
        CheckDisposed();

        reasonPhrase = value; // It's OK to have a 'null' reason phrase
    }
}
```

Please describe in more detail your problem